# Is there a way to have an optional TBS Sub Block?

Tags: opentbs

I have a word document and I was wondering how I can still print out the states even if I have nothing for cities. Lets say for California I have 20 cities, but for Texas I still don't have any entries.

```
 [state;block=begin;sub1 = cities]
   [state.State] 
       [state_sub1;block=begin]
          [state_sub1.City]
       [state_sub1;block=end]
 [state;block=end]
```

Comment: Can you give an example ?
If you use the relative syntax (like [state.State;block=tbs:p]...) then it could be without relic.

Answer (score 0):

[state;block=begin;sub1 = (cities)]